# Network discovery on a Mac

Tags: macos, networking

Is there a Mac/Unix commands that lets you see the local network in terms of machines/IP addresses? If there's something on the Mac that is gui-based that would be great too.

Comment: Grammar Nazi: Are there OS X/Unix commands that enable you to see the local machines and their IP Addresses? A GUI version would be appreciate much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IP Scanner 2.5 for OS X. http://10base-t.com/ Looking for others, but that's the only real one I've found for OS X.

Comment: Shame it only shows the first 6 services and then requires an extended license...

Answer (score 12):

`ping` the broadcast address (the broadcast address is printed as part of the output to `ifconfig en0`)

The hosts answering are on your local network. (You may also try `arp -a` but that only keeps track of recently contacted hosts so you may want to run it after the broadcast.)

Comment: I imagine on most home networks directed-broadcast is probably not disabled so this works great in that scenario, +1

Comment: On my office network it works fairly well. However, windows hosts don't answer the broadcast - I imagine due to security built into SP2 - so your nmap solution is likely better.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but didn't quite work on my home network (my Windows Home Server did not respond to this -- I suppose because it drops these packets or has its ICMP port turned off)

Answer (score 4):

There is a program called [Bonjour Browser](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/13388) that will list well known services that have registered on your local network.  I believe that most Macs have one or more registered protocols by default.

Comment: There's also Bonjeff (https://github.com/lapcat/Bonjeff/releases)

Comment: There is also SSDP Browser for browsing UPnP devices, which is the Windows equivalent to Bonjour. It's a GUI app for listing those devices. https://github.com/tempelmann/SSDP-Browser/releases/

Answer (score 2):

The only way to reliably do this is to scan the network using ping sweeps and similar techniques looking for open ports etc on various addresses. You can do that with [**nmap**](http://nmap.org/download.html) which is available for OS X. See http://www.netadmintools.com/art406.html for an example.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, as [diciu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544926/network-discovery-on-a-mac/544971#544971) pointed out, you can usually ping the broadcast address and/or use your arp cache as well. This will probably work for most home networks where directed broadcast is allowed.

If not, then you would need to run a ping sweep with a tool like nmap to individually check each address for an available host. Many network discovery/scanning tools can check for more than just ping, looking for listening ports, SNMP, etc. as well.

Answer (score 2):

in the days of tiger (10.4) every mac broadcast a 'presence' service on bonjour, which made finding macintoshes on the network a snap.  alas, no more...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [netdiscover](https://github.com/alexxy/netdiscover) on Mac OS, which is based on ARP packets. It will send ARP requests and scan the response.

For example, run netdiscover command `sudo netdiscover -i en0 -r 10.106.0.0/16` in my local network would bring the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) but that seems to be a bit much for your stated goals.

<del>OS X ships with [netstat](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html), or open Up /Applications/Utilities/Network Utility.app, perhaps this will work for you?</del>

**EDIT:** oops. netstat doesn't do what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

angry IP scanner for a no mus - no fuss IP scanner with basic port scanning.
NMap and Zenmap for the big power scans.
I actually use both together, as nmap can get easily sidetracked by certain reverse proxy boxes.